# Reasoning for differentiation and integration being (almost) inverses of each other

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Is the following reasoning valid for why differentiation and integration are (almost) inverse operations?

Antiderivatives/indefinite integrals are defined as:

$\int f(x)\ dx=F(x)$ where $F'(x)=f(x)$.

So using this, we can say that:

$\int f'(x)\ dx=F(x)=f(x)+C$ since $F'(x)=(f(x)+C)'=f'(x)$.

Hence, the integral of a derivative gives the original function (apart from a constant).

Similarly,

$(\int f(x)\ dx)'=F'(x)=f(x)$ since $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Hence, the derivative of an integral gives the original function.

Comment: I dislike using the notation $\int f(x) \, dx$ for an antiderivative of $f$ (or the set of all possible anti derivatives of $f$) because it blurs the distinction between the concept of a definite integral and the concept of an antiderivative. Those are two distinct concepts that happen to have a surprising connection (at least, it’s surprising at first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the derivative of the (or an) antiderivative of $f$ is $f$ itself is in fact unremarkable. The remarkable bit, and the point of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, is that the definite and indefinite integral are basically the same thing: For $f$ continuous, the Riemann sum $\int_a^b dx\; f(x)$ is just $F(b) - F(a)$. That fact isn't obvious at all; a bit of work gives some geometric intuition behind it, but proving it rigorously takes more than a bit of work. (There's also another part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and it has other formulations in terms of, e.g., the Lebesgue integral; but this statement seems closest to what you're going for.) The distinction might be a bit clearer in multiple dimensions, where an integral over a surface or volume makes sense, but it takes a bit of work on differential forms to get anything approaching an antiderivative.